# tmux "error connecting to /private/tmp/tmux-501/default (Socket operation on non-socket)" macOS

Tags: macos, homebrew, tmux

Installed tmux on my local machine via

```
brew install tmux
```

Trying to run it and getting this

```
error connecting to /private/tmp/tmux-501/default (Socket operation on non-socket)
```

Could someone to suggest something to do with it? Seems something wrong with socket but in all tutorials I have to install and just run it.

I tried:
To reinstall - nothing as a result. Any command such as `tmux new`, `tmux attach` gives the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Tmux source. Be sure that it's saved with the correct information or conf.  Use and editor like vscode and make sure you've saved everything